# Create an alias with a variable in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, bash

How do you use variables in an alias? For example if pbcopy will allow me to access the clipboard (copied ip address) and assign it to `$ip` I could copy an IP address and then use an `alias` such as the below failed example.

```
alias go='ip=pbpaste | ssh $ip -l pete'
```

Comment: See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html

Comment: The Command-V key combination copies the contents of the clipboard into the command line in the terminal window.  You can highlight the text you want and copy it to the clipboard with Command-C.  Are you looking for something else?  I routinely use these to copy information from the browser (eg Stack Overflow) into a file for testing, for example.

Comment: I wanted to import the copied ip address into a command to automate numerous repeated ssh logins. x = clipboard. Then my script or alias will enter: ssh root@x. I realize it isn't that much typing but 50 times per day makes it worth it- plus there is a different syntax for various devices which I will incorporate too.

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby?

Comment: I thought it might be easier to write in ruby vs. bash? Or nothing is a better answer I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to create a variable or pipe, simply use a subshell:

```
alias go='ssh $(pbpaste) -l pete'
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually use [pbpaste/pbcopy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html), but you may want to find something with a history for your uses.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a function in place of an alias, as functions can take arguments:

```
function go {
    ssh "$1" -l pete
}
```

After copying the IP address, you can type "go ", paste the IP address with Command-V, and hit return.

You can also duplicate the accepted answer to avoid having to paste the address manually:

```
function go {
    ssh $(pbpaste) -l pete
}
```

so the real message here is to start thinking in terms of shell functions instead of aliases, since according to the bash man page

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.